# Apollo IOS Codegen CLI duplicate files

Tags: ios, xcode, apollo, apollo-client

I generated graphql swift files using Apollo Codegen - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/code-generation/codegen-cli

But when I added files to the project then I see the duplicate swift files under the fragments folder and Schema->Objects folder.

Below is the error
Filname "XXX.grapgql.swift" used twice.

> "path/customer/Fragraments/XXX.grapgql.swift"

> "path/customer/Schema/Objects/XXX.grapgql.swift"

Appreciate any help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you post this issue in [Apollo GraphQL official community.](https://community.apollographql.com/) The team that support the iOS client regularly monitors this forum.